# Angular 6 Template driven form cross field validation clear errors

Tags: angular, cross-validation, customvalidator

Inside HTML:

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { ValidationErrors, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { RangeValidator } from "./range-validator";

export const rangeValidator: ValidatorFn = ( formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {        
    let fromAge = '', toAge = '';
    if(formGroup && formGroup.parent && formGroup.parent.controls && formGroup.parent.controls['ageFrom'] ){
        fromAge = formGroup.parent.controls['ageFrom'];
    }
    if(formGroup && formGroup.parent && formGroup.parent.controls && formGroup.parent.controls['ageTo'] ){
        toAge = formGroup.parent.controls['ageTo'];
    }
    if ( fromAge !== "" && toAge !== "") {
        const rangeVal: RangeValidator = new RangeValidator();
        const ret = rangeVal.validateRange(fromAge,toAge);
        return ret;
    }
    return null;
};


@Directive({
    selector: '[range-validator]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: RangeValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class RangeValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('change', ['$event.target'])
    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        return rangeValidator(control);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
            <input matInput type="number" 
            minlength="1" 
            maxlength="150" 
            placeholder="From" 
           [(ngModel)]="ageFromInput"  
           name="ageFrom"   required 
           #ageFrom="ngModel" 
           range-validator>                     
            <mat-hint *ngIf="ageFrom.hasError('rangeInvalid')">
              From age should be less than to age
            </mat-hint>    
          </div>
          <div>
            <input matInput type="number" 
            minlength="1" 
            maxlength="150" 
            placeholder="From" 
            [(ngModel)]="ageFromInput"  
            name="ageFrom" 
            required #ageFrom="ngModel"  
            range-validator> 
            <mat-hint *ngIf="!ageFrom['valid'] 
            &&  ageFrom['touched']">
              <p *ngIf="ageFrom.errors?.pattern">
              Please enter a valid From age</p>
            </mat-hint>
          </div>
```

The issue is I implemented cross-field validation using the template-driven form, I have an input field "From Age" and the other input field "To Age", I applied attribute validator for both the inputs. The event is firing as expected. But here comes the problem. The scenario is if I entered From Age as 15 and ToAge is 20 and after I edited FromAge as 25 and ToAge 30 Then my custom validator is not making the FromAge field as valid. And I am unable to submit the form until unless I go and edit the field ( From Age) again.

Comment: Why you created custom directive for this? it could be handled via custom validators which angular reactive form gives out of the box, I would definitely go with custom validators

Comment: @KamranKhatti  the validation should be done by comparing both the fields and Validators which are given in the framework will not suffice my requirement.

Comment: Why not all you need to compare two fields data if those not satisfy with your requirement you need to through error correct?

Comment: Solved it by my-self, clearing the errors if the error object is null.if(ret === null){
            formGroup.parent.controls['ageFrom'].setErrors(null);
            formGroup.parent.controls['ageTo'].setErrors(null);
        }